# AngularJS dont clear array after POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post

**PROBLEM**

Hello! When I POST data to backend all works fine, but when I hit ENTER and POST an empty field it POST same value again. Before posting anything I cant POST empty field, but after I enter vaule once and then send empty field I can POST same value like 99999x times. If after sending 1st value I enter new one it ofc POST new one, but then I can again post that new value 999999x times by clicking ENTER on empty field. As backend I use laravel 5 if this info can help in solution.

**MY CODE**

HTML

```
<h1>{{ tasksdata.lists.name }}</h1>
<hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="task in tasksdata.tasks">
    <h2>{{ task.description }}</h2>
    </div>
<h2><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))"> + </a></h2>
<input type="text" ng-model="taskname" id="adiv" ng-keydown="key($event)" value="" onkeydown="hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))" class="form-control" style="font:24px bold; display: none" placeholder="NEW TASK" />
```

Script

```
function hideshow(which){

if (which.style.display=="none"){
    which.style.display="block";
    which.value="";
    which.focus();
}

$(which).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        which.style.display = "none"
    }
});

$(which).blur(function () {
    which.style.display = "none"
});
}
```

Angular for POST

```
myApp.controller('tasksController', ['$scope', '$log', '$http', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, $log, $http,$routeParams ){

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost/anydocopy/public/lists/' + $routeParams.id
        })
            .success(function (d) {
                console.log(d);
                $scope.tasksdata = d;
            });
            var task = {};
        console.log('before sending');
        console.log(task);
        $scope.key = function($event){
            console.log($event.keyCode);
            if ($event.keyCode == 13) {
                task = {
                    description: $scope.taskname,
                    list_id: $routeParams.id
                };

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/anydocopy/public/lists/'+$routeParams.id,
                    data: task
                })
                    .success(function () {

                        console.log('true');
                        task = {};
                        console.log('after sending');
                        console.log(task);
                        $http({
                            method: 'GET',
                            url: 'http://localhost/anydocopy/public/lists/' + $routeParams.id
                        })
                            .success(function (d) {
                                console.log(d);
                                $scope.tasksdata = d;
                            });


                    })
                    .error(function(){
                        console.log('false');
                    })
            }};

    }]);
```

**WHAT I TRYED**

I define new task array before posting, then I fill it with data from html and POST them. If POST was successful then array is empty. In console before and after POST array is always empty, so I don't understand how can it send same data as before when I click ENTER.. Also every time when I show my input text it's value is "".

Comment: I feel that this would be a lot easier to troubleshoot (or perhaps the problem wouldn't exist at all) if you didn't mix vanilla JS event handlers and show/hide logic with Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting:
    $scope.taskname =""; 
when the post is successful.
I think the 2 way binding is setting your input field back to your previous entry, but you can't see it, because of the display:none. If you use your developer tools, you'll likely see that the input field contains the same value as before.